# How to find by foreign id?

Tags: themoviedb-api

I try to get a result by themovidb API with a thetvdb ID
I'm not sure what I'm doin wrong

[Documentation](http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#find)

My try to access the API

> http://api.themoviedb.org/3/find/71663?api_key=XXX

My result

> {"status_code":6,"status_message":"Invalid id - The pre-requisite id is invalid or not found"}

ID [71663](http://thetvdb.com/?tab=series&id=71663&lid=14) on thetvdb
I'm pretty sure I get this working before - but this time I can't figure out whats wrong. I think I'm missing something that defines that I'm looking for a TV show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the `?external_source` parameter

> http://api.themoviedb.org/3/find/tt0266543?api_key=XXX&external_source=imdb_id